# Marking correct answer should not be counted as Vote

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting

In my reputation view, I am often annoyed with the fact that approvals counts as votes.

In my world, theres upvotes and downvotes. Marking an answer as correct is important, but not a vote.

This occurs when you have "collapsed" entries like the one below:

[image: Vote count]

When the entry is collapsed, it says 2 votes. But when I expand it, there is only one vote, and one approval. Either it should say "1 vote" or "2 events".

Approvals, bounty payouts and bounty deposits also increase the number of votes. So a reply that got one vote, got approved, and got a bounty is mentioned as "3 votes", but only one of them being a vote.

Its not a big thing, but as we strive for perfection, this diamond could still use a little polishing :]

I have tagged this as a bug, since I believe it should be fixed. But feel free to bring your views to the table on this one.

Comment: Good catch.. I would suggest something like "[x] votes and accept" or in your example "1 vote and accept"

Comment: As we strive for perfection? No sir, I would never do such a thing. I see this as such a miniscule... thing that it doesn't really matter (In my opinion).

Comment: yes :] but to keep the width reduced, i suggested "[x] events" to sum it up.

Comment: @Gabe : I know it's not a major issue, but in any case we shouldn't have a system saying "You got 2 votes" if you actually only got one. Also, in this example i have expanded the entry, all entries are collapsed at start.

Comment: @NilsMunch Actually I have noticed this, the whole vote list thing is unclear... I suggest they also seperate +1's and -1's, it can be confusing and make us wonder where rep came from/disapeared to.

Comment: @Gabe Yes, that would be neat as well :]

Comment: Everything you listed *is a vote*, so they're displayed as such.  We will be tweaking this view in a more complete way coming up, but there will be no changes for this...it's been brought up on meta already, without any better working suggestions ("events" is not correct either).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does say 2 votes in your case (in my case, 3 votes) but consider choosing the best answer as a vote in where its a poll where the first vote decides the winner, and there is only one votee. So its still a vote essentially... And you can just do the following to see a detailed view of that question:

[image]

[image]

Sorry for my horrendous mspaint skills, but if you really want to see it that bad you could just do this. I somewhat agree with your argument, however, because it doesn't specify enough.

When you see the votes without the dropdown, it might say 13 votes. You could sift through the dropdown and see that 1 was the best answer, 3 were -1's and the rest were +1's, but there should be a different word for all this.

I have been trying to think of a word that would meet the requirements for this predicament, and I really couldn't think of anything good. But a bad example would be: 3 activities, 3 opinions, 3 changes, 3 mice, not sure. If anyone comes up with a good idea please leave a comment.

Comment: +1 for freehand arrow, -1 for no freehand circle, -1 for curly brace, +1 for the curly brace being so badly-drawn that it's funny.

Comment: +1 for admitting that you used mspaint. (And I agree.)